# pgfgantt: extra garbage printed

Tags: pgfgantt

I have this strange problem where at the bottom of a gantt chart extra information gets printed. The minimal working example below produces the following result for me.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[time slot format=isodate-yearmonth, compress calendar]{2015-1-1}{2015-12-31}
\gantttitlecalendar{year,month}\\
\ganttbar{Item 1}{2015-1-1}{2015-6-1}\\
\ganttbar{Item 2}{2015-7-1}{2015-12-31}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Some information: TeXLive 2014.34872-1, LuaTeX beta-0.79.1, pgfgantt 2013/06/01 v4.0.

Comment: It is not *extra* garbage but simply garbage, unless a certain amount of garbage was expected!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying the `time slot specifier` as `{2015-1-1}{2015-12-31}` i.e., `yyyy-mm-dd`. This corresponds to `time slot format=isodate`.  When you specify `time slot format=isodate-yearmonth`, the *tss* format should be `(yyyy-mm)`. So changing the `tss` to

```
{2015-01}{2015-12}
```

as in

```
\begin{ganttchart}[time slot format=isodate-yearmonth, compress calendar]{2015-01}{2015-12}
```

should solve your problem.

Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[time slot format=isodate-yearmonth, compress calendar]{2015-01}{2015-12}
\gantttitlecalendar{year,month}\\
\ganttbar{Item 1}{2015-1-1}{2015-6-1}\\
\ganttbar{Item 2}{2015-7-1}{2015-12-31}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem. I can additionally say that the today= option should also only be given in the yyyy-mm format or else it will produce similar problem.